# MongoDB restore. Recover after failure

Tags: backup, mongodb, restore, timeout

Is it possible to resume mongo backup restoration after failure? I'm getting an error

```
2021-07-01T23:35:01.944+0200    Failed: dbname.collectionname_backup: error restoring from archive 'mongodb-db-backup.gz': connection(db-url.com:27017[-4]) incomplete read of message header: read tcp 0.0.0.0:55697->1.1.1.1:27017: read: operation timed out
2021-07-01T23:35:01.944+0200    851000 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.
```

Also probably it's possible to make the timeout longer?

UPD. The command I use to restore.

```
mongorestore --noIndexRestore --host mongo.host.co --gzip --archive=mongodb-backup.gz -u ..... -p ....... --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. What command did you initially use to start the restore? What command was used to create the backup? Could you please [edit] your question and these details? Thanks. Currently you are asking for a solution to an error message. That's hard to accomplish without more details.

Comment: Thank you. Just added the command I use to restore. I don't have a command used to backup because the backup was made not by me.

Comment: If I try to use the same command to resume the restore I got a lot of errors because of duplicated keys.